# Implementation of predictive variance in Gaussian process regression of scikit-learn

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, algorithms, gaussian-process, linear-algebra

I'm studying the implementation of Gaussian Process Regression in scikit-learn to get a better understanding of the topic.
There I've stumbled upon the following snippet:

```py
if return_cov:
    v = cho_solve((self.L_, True), K_trans.T)  # Line 5
    y_cov = self.kernel_(X) - K_trans.dot(v)  # Line 6
    return y_mean, y_cov
```

It is from the file [_gpr.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/gaussian_process/_gpr.py#L22), around line 340.

The line numbers 5 and 6 in the comments apparently refer to the corresponding lines in algorithm 2.1 of the book  [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.GaussianProcess.org/gpml):

[image: algorithm 2.1]

`\` is the matrix inversion operator like in MATLAB.

**My question is** Why is it not $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}$ in sklearn but instead ${\mathbf{k}^\ast}^T\mathbf{v}$?
I think it is wrong from dimensional analysis: $L$ has units of a standard deviation and $\mathbf{k}_\ast$ of a variance, so $\mathbf{v}$ has those of a standard deviation too. But then ${\mathbf{k}^\ast}^T\mathbf{v}$ has units of a standard deviation to the power of $1.5$ and not units of a variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the fact, that [cho_solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cho_solve.html) is different from `\`, and so sklearn's defintion of $v$ somewhat confusingly ends up not being the same as in the book.

In sklearn `v_sk = cho_solve((self.L_, True), K_trans.T)` would correspond to solving the system
$K v_{sk} = \mathbf{k}_*^\top$ with $LL^\top=K$ being the Cholesky decomposition of training data covariance, `self.L_`$=L$, `K_trans`$=\mathbf{k}_*$ and `K`=$K$.

However line 5 in the book $\mathbf{v} := L \setminus \mathbf{k}_*$ corresponds to solving $ L \mathbf{v} =  \mathbf{k}_*$. Substitute the corresponding definitions in the next line and you will end up with the same posterior covariance matrices.

For a better understanding of how `cho_solve` corresponds to forward/backward substitution compare how line 3 is implemented in [_gpr.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c42d54b26137a456c510c5fdba1ba23e0/sklearn/gaussian_process/_gpr.py#L272) :

$\mathbf{\alpha} := L^\top \setminus ( L \setminus \mathbf{y} )$

`self.alpha_ = cho_solve((self.L_, True), self.y_train_)`

Comment: Never would have guessed that the $v$ is not the same! Thank you very much!